# How to set static local IP for VirtualBox?

Tags: connection, virtualbox

How to set static local IP for VirtualBox?

In windows 10 I have VirtualBox with OS Ubuntu.
And have IP this machine 192.168.0.102
 **but after reboot PC or Virtualbox sometimes IP changed to 192.168.0.100.**

How I can make always IP  **192.168.0.102 for Ubuntu**? (like static IP).

In networks VB I select network bridge

Comment: In VirtualBox you can just set the MAC-Address for the network interface(s), the IP depends on the settings in your guest OS/the DHCP server in your network. Change to [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518806/set-ip-address-and-stuff-on-ubuntu)

Comment: So if I set up IP in Ubuntu. Then VB will not change it?